# pgsync.exc.ForeignKeyError: 'No foreign key relationship between "public.book" and "public.book_author"'

Tags: python, postgresql, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch indexing not working through **pgsync**

below is my schema.json

```
[
  {
    "database": "book",
    "index": "book_data",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "table": "book",
        "schema": "public",
        "columns": ["id", "title", "isbin"],
        "children": [
          {
            "table": "book_author",
            "schema": "public",
            "columns": ["id", "book_id", "author"],
            "relationship": {
              "variant": "object",
              "type": "one_to_one"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Above table don't have foreign key constrain due to that
**pgsync** throwing error while creat indexing

`pgsync.exc.ForeignKeyError: 'No foreign key relationship between "public.book" and "public.book_author"'`

If I do the same with table who has a foreign key defined then it works properly.

Any solution on how to do this without adding foreign key constrains.

Comment: Why do you not want to aviod the proper way; just create a foreign key. After all this is the reason they exist in the first place.  If you are really set against it then you could completely hide the fact the tables are related by removing the relationship definition. Then writing database triggers to select from book for the book_id in book_author to ensure it exists. You also need to check on any update to either table, and what happens when you delete from book that has a book_author child, and probably more.  Sounds like a lot of work to avoid using what already built in.

Comment: @Belayer first of all thank you for your reply. 
But it too old and a huge database that's why I wanted a separate dataset out of using it pgsync.

Answer (score 1):

pgsync now supports user-defined foreign key relationships.
Have a look at the tutorial in the docs [here](https://pgsync.com/tutorial/relationship-with-user-defined-foreign-key/) or an [example](https://github.com/toluaina/pgsync/blob/master/examples/book/schema.json#L87) in the repo

Comment: I have one to many relationships having table1 and table2 in db says uuid => uuid[] like {uuid1,uuid2,uuid3} mapping. How can I achieve this?

I tried 
type: one_to_many,
variant: scalar,
foriegn_key : {
       child: ["id"], // table2
       parent: ["users"] // table1 each tuple having records like {uuid1,uuid2,uuid3} 
}
this throws error: operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]

Comment: what I actually want is to have the ability to map scalar variant with one_to_many type relationships. I am not able to find an example of such type.